# wildcard dot-star to ignore delimeter

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, wildcard, splunk

I am trying to write a splunk query that basically extracts fields between delimiter "," and puts the value in a variable.

I want to extract everything between 2 commas.

```
,extract this@#$,
,extract this-=@#$, etc
```

Now, there is not an option to not give any regular expression and just get everything between `, ,`.

So closest I can think is `,.*,`  .. however `.*` would get greedy and match everything else.

Is there a regular expression I can use to stop wildcard matching after a `,` is encountered?

I tried

```
.*$,
.*,
```

which didn't work.

Comment: Try `.*?,`.  In most regex flavors, a ? after * makes it non-greedy.  I don't have splunk experience, so I can't confirm that's the case for your example.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about splunk but in most languages you could try

```
/\,([^,]*)\,/
```

-- match all characters that aren't a comma. extraction will be in \1.  Not sure if you'll need the escapes in front of the commas.

Answer (score 1):

Use following regex in your splunk search query, it will extract required filed as "FIELDNAME"

```
| rex "(?i)\,(?P<FIELDNAME>[^ ][a-z0-9#-@$ ]+)\,\s"
```

Considering after "," (after field) there is space hence i have added "\s", without "\s" it will also work.